# MATLAB remove NaN values from matrix and shift values left

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compute column-wise differences in the following matrix:

```
A = 
     0       NaN       NaN    0.3750       NaN
     NaN    0.1250    0.2500  0.3750       NaN
```

I would like to obtain:

```
0.3750 NaN    NaN
0.1250 0.1250 0.1250
```

Where I am essentially taking a columnwise difference, skipping NaN values and shifting values to the left.

A one-dimensional case would be:

```
A = [0 NaN 0.250 0.375 NaN 0.625];
NaN_diff(A) = [0.250 0.125 0.250];
```

Any way to do this efficiently in MATLAB without using inefficient find() queries per row?

Comment: This isn't clear, if you're "skipping NaNs", then why are there still NaNs in your example output?

Comment: Sorry, I added those NaNs to make sure the matrix was rectangular - rows with more numbers will have longer diffs. They could arbitrarily be zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that vectorizes most of the operations:

```
notNan = ~isnan(A);
numNN  = sum(notNan,2);

shifted = NaN(size(A));

for r = 1:size(A,1)
   myRow = A(r,:);
   shifted(r,1:numNN(r)) = myRow(notNan(r,:));
end

nanDiff = diff(shifted,1,2);
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch` error for this. Perhaps you meant `1:numNN(r)` inside the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative vectorized solution:

```
%// Convert to cell array without NaNs
[rows, cols] = size(A);
C = cellfun(@(x)x(~isnan(x)), mat2cell(A, ones(1, rows), cols), 'Uniform', 0);

%// Compute diff for each row and pad
N = max(sum(~isnan(A), 2));
C = cellfun(@(x)[diff(x) nan(1, N - length(x))], C, 'Uniform', 0);

%// Convert back to a matrix
nandiff = vertcat(C{:});
```

If you want to pad the result matrix with zeroes instead of `NaN` values, change the `nan` function call in `nan(1, N - length(x))` to `zeros`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method that does require you to loop over each row, but should still have decent performance and feels very intuitive to me.

```
B = NaN(size(A,1),size(A,2)-1)

for i = 1:size(A,1)
   idx = ~isnan(A(:,i))
   B(i,1:sum(idx)) = diff(A(i,idx))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this is a rather old question, but for people like me who stumble into this page, here is a simpler (imho) solution to the question:

```
A = [0 NaN 0.250 0.375 NaN 0.625];
A(isnan(A))=[]; % identify index of NaN values and remove them from the array
B = diff(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple solution without using a loop [but assuming all values are in ascending order]:

```
A=[0       NaN       NaN    0.3750       NaN;NaN    0.1250    0.2500  0.3750       NaN]
A(isnan(A(:,1)))=0;
B=sort(A,2);
C=diff(B,1,2)
```